# How to delete authentication user from firebase?

Tags: reactjs, firebase-authentication

My idea is that all users have right to delete their account and my project is to help them.

I find one easy function which do not work
firebase.js

```
const auth = getAuth(app);
```

paneluser.jsx

```
import { useAuthState } from "react-firebase-hooks/auth";
import { auth, db, logout, storage } from "./firebase";

funt panel() {
    const [user] = useAuthState(auth);


const deleteAcount   = () => {
user.delete();
}

return (<> 
<button onClick={deleteAcount}/>)
```

Comment: What is `funt`?

Comment: ``` function panel () { ```